# issue with with suexec command when i try to initialise virtualmin on a pc with webmin installed and working

Tags: suexec

I am trying to initialise Virtualmin. After installing it via Webmin->Module->new module installation screen.

This is the message that I am getting in Webmin:

```
The Suexec command on your system is configured to only run scripts under /var/www, but the Virtualmin virtual server home directory is /home. CGI and PHP scripts run as domain owners will not be executed.
```

How do I correct this error so that Virtualmin can start working?

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you told which distro you are using.

Anyhow, on debian-based distros you would need to edit the `/etc/apache2/suexec/www-data` file and add the `/home` path.

If you do not have that file, make sure `apache2-suexec-custom` apt package is installed.